# Folded menu navigation with KnpMenu

Tags: symfony, menu, tree, navigation, knpmenu

I want to use KnpMenu for a current project to handle my navigation tree logic. 
I have build a menu tree like this:

```
use Knp\Menu\Matcher\Matcher;
use Knp\Menu\MenuFactory;
use Knp\Menu\Renderer\ListRenderer;

$factory = new MenuFactory();
$menu = $factory->createItem('my_menu');

$menu->addChild('home', array('uri' => '/', 'label' => 'Home'))
     ->addChild('about', array('uri' => 'about', 'label' => 'About'));

$cat1 = $menu->addChild('category_1', array('uri' => 'category_1', 'label' => 'Category 1'));
$cat1_1 = $cat1->addChild('category_1_1', array('uri' => 'category_1_1', 'label' => 'Category 1.1'));
$cat1_1->addChild('category_1__1', array('uri' => 'category_1_1_1', 'label' => 'Category 1.1.1'));
$cat1_1->addChild('category_1_1_2', array('uri' => 'category_1_1_2', 'label' => 'Category 1.1.2'))->setCurrent(true);
$cat1->addChild('category_1_2', array('uri' => 'category_1_2', 'label' => 'Category 1.2'));

$renderer = new ListRenderer(new Matcher());
echo $renderer->render($menu);
```

I was wondering if it is possible to render a folded menu tree where only the currently active menu items are displayed. The other items should not be displayed.
In the documentation I haven't found a way to accomplish this.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you only want to have the menu 'unfolded' if the parent is active?
If so, then yes, I had the same requirement, and there is a PR open for it here https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/pull/85

Currently as it's not merged I am using my branch to replace the tagged KnpMenu in composer.

```
//composer.json excerpt
...
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@github.com:catchamonkey/KnpMenu"
    }
],
require: {
    ...
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "dev-display_children_if_ancestor_current as 2.0.0",
    ...
}
...
```

You then tag the top level item with this behaviour, so to make your category_1 only expand if a child is active (or it is active), you would do

```
$cat1->setDisplayChildrenIfAncestorCurrent(true);
```

And this is handled by the twig rendered change here https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/pull/85/files#L2R74

Comment: Hey, thanks for your fast answer. You understood correctly that's exactly what I am looking for. I looked at your branch for the KnpMenu. What I don't understand is where the logic is which checks whether the current MenuItem has displayChildrenIfAncestorCurrent set to true and decides whether this item should be displayed or not.

Comment: @user1036651 I have updated with the example and where it's used.

Comment: I don't use Knpmenu in a Symfony2 context and thus don't use twig. But shouldn't the logic whether a child is displayed or not be in the MenuItem class anyway? The same way the class decides not to display children when "DisplayChildren" is set to false?

Comment: Yes I guess the further 'up' the chain the better, my PR prompted some discussion to have this done differently, but so far we haven't got there, so I haven't changed it further, should be easy enough though as you say.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. I will add the missing part!